# Does signal strength deteriorate from router to router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

This is the situation, at my friend’s restaurant is a *really* old router (Fast FW150R; let’s call it A), connected to a modem, connected to A is also 3 other wireless surveillance cameras. The video quality on the cameras was so choppy/skippy so I got him a new router (Fast FW310R) in hopes of a better connection.

Now for some reason I can’t connect B directly to the modem, I can only get Internet by connecting B to the modem through A (something to do with dynamic/static address that I can’t figure out). I’ve given up trying to get B to connect to the modem directly, so currently B is routing through A.

Now my question is, should the video quality be better with the new configuration or should I stick to the old? I’m only assuming the new setup will be better because the router is new and has 3 antennas, but if the signal strength deteriorates, then it’s probably worse overall? Is there anything I can do setup-wise to ensure a better connection to the cameras?

Comment: @JakeGould sorry, i was just under the assumption that the old one was just inferior haha. but here it is, the old is a _Fast FW150R_ and the new one is a _Fast FW310R_. i'm not sure what you mean by wifi protocol:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you connect the new wifi box via cable and disable the wifi on the old one, then it should work better and there is no problem with signal quality.

If, however, you connect the new box as an extender wirelessly, then they may cause more interference to each other and there are two wireless sections that can have signal issues.

So the proper way to do it is to use cabled connection to the new wifi box and have wifi enabled only on that one. Of course depends on the cameras and other signal sources how much it will help, but it won't be worse at least.

Comment: ah yes, thanks, this is what i was wondering as well. as it stands, both the routers are next to each other with both wifi's enabled and i wasn't sure if that would cause some bit of an interference. i guess there's really no harm in disabling wifi on the old one

Comment: also, does it make a difference if the old router has a LAN data rate of 150Mbs while the new has 300? in other words, is the new one being throttled by the old?

Comment: @timoseewho That is the WiFi data rate, it will not affect the cable data rate, which I assume might be 100Mbps only.

Comment: ahhh thanks again, i was thinking it meant wifi but they worded it like it was the rate for a cable connection-_-. just for future reference, if i did connect a 1000Mbps to a 100Mbps, would that 1k'er be throttled?

Comment: @timoseewho It will negotiate a suitable speed, so they would be connected at 100M and the faster device may buffer data if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you restart the modem after connecting the new router to it?

Some modems store the MAC address (kind of like a hardware id) of whatever device is connected to them when they boot, and will only communicate with that device until powered off then on.

To answer your question, no signal strength doesn't deteriorate as you add more devices capable of emitting their own signal, though signal quality can be impacted negatively due to the extra radio noise on the same or adjacent channels

Also, does the restaurant use microwaves often? Microwaves generate massive ~2.4GHz interference when running. Enough to cause a complete standstill of any network traffic if within a few yards of one.

Comment: thanks for the swift response. i did restart both modem and B when i made the initial connection. unfortunately i'm in a foreign country, so i'm not exactly sure how their internet hookups work lol (China), maybe the tech did something with A to be able to connect to the provided modem. the restaurant does use a microwave quite heavily, but the video quality is still crappy regardless of use:(. should i have picked up a 5HGz router instead?